# access to foreign key fields with fields name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I need access to foreign key fields with string fields name:
for example:
In a def in Document model , I need access to customer__customer_name [**customer model** -> **customer_name field**]

Mycode:

```
class Customer(LaundryModel, models.Model):
    customer_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Document(LaundryModel,models.Model):
    document_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey("customer.customer", on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 related_name='+')

    json_fields=["customer__customer_name", "customer__customer_code"]
    
    def send_email(self):
        ###### in this place Need access to customer_name and customer_name from customer foreign key  ######
```

I try to this with getattr or values or another but not working

Comment: In your `send_mail` method,`self.customer.customer_name` should make it.

Comment: @Guillaume I need access with string field name for example "customer__customer_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model field is simply an attribute. So if you want to get it using a string, you should use `getattr`:

```py
getattr(object, name)
getattr(object, name, default)
```